# React - components not updating correctly on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a React site which has several sections. I'd like to pass certain props to the sections, but only when they are in the viewport. To this end, I included a scroll event listener that should change the "active" section
every time `window.scrollY` passes the boundaries of the active section (either by leaving it behind (`window.scrollY > section.getBoundingClientRect().bottom`), or by returning to the beginning of the page (`window.scrollY < section.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight`)).

The thing is, it does not seem to work.

here's the demo: https://codepen.io/LuisChDev/pen/REVPWd?editors=0112

any ideas on why the code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you set your scroll listener:

```
const {curSec} = this.state;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > boundaries[curSec].bottom - 80) {
  ...
```

At this time, `curSec` is 0. `cursec` doesn't get updated automatically inside the scrollhandler, therefore you are only setting up boundary for the first div.

You should change it to something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  boundaries.forEach((boundary, i) => {
    if (window.scrollY > boundary.top) {
      this.setState({ curSec: i });
    }
    else if (window.scrollY > boundary.bottom + 20) {
      this.setState({ curSec: i - 1 });
    }
  });
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/d4rek/pen/WLjwwr?editors=0010)

Your boundary check is also not working, so I adjusted it a little bit. This way, the scroll listener actually checks boundaries for all divs, not just the first one.

---

However, you should look into [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), since it's meant to do exactly this but with better performance.

---

Also, a small tip for ya: don't keep updating the codepen which you share to stackoverflow -- you should paste your code into the question & link to a new codepen fork.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for editing the example. I will remember to fork it in the future.

Comment: @MyNameIsMethos Im glad it helped! Once you got it working, check out the use of ‘ref’ in React as well  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

Your boundary object has top and bottom properties as `undefined`.

`document.getElementById(x).getBoundingClientRect.top`

change it to

`document.getElementById(x).getBoundingClientRect().top`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already changed them, not sure if you can see - and it did work the first time, but it does not change again when I move it further, or when I go back. Do you have any idea of what may be causing this behavior?